# Jmeter Performance testing: Thread leakage

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter, performance-testing

Can JMeter detect thread leakage also in a java application. That is one can observe a thread leakage by JVisualvm but is there not any plugin etc. for JMeter that can detect thread leakage in a Java application. If not then is there any other performance testing tool that can detect thread leakage in a java application and why Jmeter can not do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the thread pools you're looking for are exposed over JMX, you can use the JMXMon plugin: https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/

Comment: Is this component dedicated for thread leakage or Memory leakage? Because memory leakage is different than thread leakage.

Comment: This component will collect metrics exposed through JMX - actually detecting any pathological behavior is then up to an analyst.